# Is there an audit trail for Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to diagnose an issue whereby blob items uploaded to Azure blob storage may be being deleted by some scheduled task.

Is there a way to see an audit trail against deleted items in Azure portal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is, it's not specific to Blob storage, but the overall storage account

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-monitor-storage-account